# Check if application is visible on the screen

Tags: c#

I want to test the startup time of two different apps, intended for the same purpose. The problem is, my definition of "startup time" for this case would be "time required until the application is **visible** on the screen".

I have implemented a way of measuring the time required to start a process using C#:

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");

while (true)
{
    if (checkifProcessExists("notepad"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Stop();
        break;
    }
}
```

The program first starts the process and then constantly checks if the process is active in Windows' process suite. This seems to "do" its job... partially. It successfully opens notepad and identifies it in the list of processes. The problem is, it returns the elapsed time way before I see Notepad on my screen.

I know the application startup time and the display time may be (and usually are) different, but my question would be: is it possible to actually check if the application is visible (on the screen, or in the taskbar)? After doing some research, I found out that this isn't possible to be done with C# alone, but can this be done by using some lower-level Windows API?

Comment: If you look for questions that ask for identifying / finding open windows (of a different app) in c# you may be able to detect _at least_ the creation of an app window with a specific title, _I think_. Now, I personally haven't done this before myself, so I am hesitant, but I really think at least that should be possible to do. Although: A Window with a specific title being found does not need to mean the app is "ready-to-use" but I guess it would be closer to it than your current measurement?

Comment: ^^ If I remeber correctly, that _may_ include having to do some P/Invoke, though. So expect to get your hands dirty.

Comment: Also mind that single measurements mean nothing. There are tons of factors influencing the start-up time of an application. So, you'll probably need to create a lot of datapoints to get a decent approximation of the real deal.

Comment: @Fildor I'm definitely not going to rely on a single measurement. Will test the software multiple times, and will also try to do some load testing on it.

Comment: @Fildor Also, thank you so much for all the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in System methods to do so

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe"); //starting a program of your choice

        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        while (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Prevents a tight loop, reduces CPU usage
            hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad"); // Use the exact window title or class name Notepad in this case
        }

        while (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        RECT rect;
        if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect))
        {
            // Check if the window size is not minimized thus ready to be interacted with "Loaded"
            if (rect.Right - rect.Left > 0 && rect.Bottom - rect.Top > 0)
            {
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Application is visible and ready after {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
        }
    }
}
```